# OCaml - Accessing absolute paths

Tags: ocaml, filepath, qtquick2

I'm developing an application where I implement the GUI in QtQuick and the logic in OCaml, using lablqt. In QtQuick I use a FileDialog to select a file. I need to use the path that the `FileDialog` returns in my OCaml program but I get an error every time I do this.

The path returned by FileDialog is `file:///home/thomas/Desktop/Sudoku/example.txt`
This is the correct path, but when I try to acces this file in OCaml I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: exception Sys_error("file:///home/thomas/Desktop/Sudoku/example.txt: No such file or directory")
```

How can I convert this path gotten from the `FileDialog` to a path I can use in OCaml?

Comment: If you try to pass the path "/home/thomas/Desktop/Sudoku/example.txt", is it working ?

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I've tried to pass "home/thomas/Desktop/Sudoku/example.txt" but that didn't work. I didn't even know there was a difference.

Comment: The difference is the "/" which indicates that the path begin from root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the protocol part from the returned url, i.e., this `file://`. You can do this either manually, or use `uri` library, that will handle it for you.